# d3 path shows path/line only up to 328 points not 329 or more

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

This is baffling and I am a newbie to d3 so managed to get it working but I am struggling since when my data crosses 328 data points, SVG simply does not show my path/line. Here is jsFiddle [working](https://jsfiddle.net/ntwgbmoe/) vs [not working](https://jsfiddle.net/ntwgbmoe/1/) (only difference is loading different jsons one with one more data points).

[image]
[image]

Code is straightforward and I have put both working and not-working jsons, just change the line `d3.json(jsonNotWorking, function(error, j) {` and replace `jsonNotWorking` with `jsonWorking`. The difference between these 2 json datasets is that one has 328 data points and the other 329 data points.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>                 
path {
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
}

line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    shape-rendering: auto;
    stroke-width: 1px;    
}
</style>   
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var slice = null, margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // parse the date / time
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z");

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Get the data
        var jsonNotWorking = "https://zutoraldiag377.blob.core.windows.net/tmp/noworkie.json";
        var jsonWorking = "https://zutoraldiag377.blob.core.windows.net/tmp/workie.json"

        d3.json(jsonNotWorking, function(error, j) {

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            try{
                data = j.slices;

                // format date
                for(p in data){
                    slice = data[p];
                    slice.date = parseTime(slice.cutTaken);
                }

                // sort out scalingo
                var totalReqsMax = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.totalRequests; });
                var totalReqsScale = Math.floor(Math.log10(totalReqsMax));

                // lines __________________
                var totalReqsLine = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { 
                    return x(d.date); 
                })
                .y(function(d) { 
                    return y(d.totalRequests / Math.pow(10, totalReqsScale)); 
                });

                // Scale the range of the data
                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));          
                y.domain([0, 10]);

                // paths ____________________
                svg.append("path")
                    .data([data])
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", totalReqsLine);


                // Add the X Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

                // Add the Y Axis
                svg.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            }
            catch (e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });        
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of your last data item has different date format (see pic, there are not milliseconds). So you cannot parse it with:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z");
```

If you can edit this JSON file I recommend you change this value. But if you cannot change it you should use another parsing function with `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z` for this data item (see [my fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntwgbmoe/14/)). It works only for this case (when the last item has different format). If your dataset will be changed during the time it must have the same date format for all item of the dataset.

[image]